# URL Rewriting in asp.net on iis

Tags: asp.net, iis, rewriting

I Have index.aspx Page
where I Have Three hyperlinks using querystring
my Index.aspx Page

```
<a href="Index.aspx?Name=Apple">Apple</a>
<a href="Index.aspx?Name=XYZ">XYZ</a>
   <a href="Index.aspx?Name=XYZ2">XYZ2</a>
```

always it will be on same page but when i click on First hyperlink it is working
 than URl is localhost:85/StateJobs/Apple
after that when i click on second time on any hyperlink url is changed 
localhost:85/StateJobs/StateJobs/XYZ
But Its Url Will Be localhost:85/StateJobs/XYZ"

My Web.Config

`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one instead:

```
<a href='<%: ResolveUrl("~/Index.aspx?Name=Apple") %>'>Apple</a>
<a href='<%: ResolveUrl("~/Index.aspx?Name=XYZ") %>'>XYZ</a>
<a href='<%: ResolveUrl("~/Index.aspx?Name=XYZ2") %>'>XYZ2</a>
```